# Commenting on each paragraph

Tags: php, drupal

I want to provide this option in Drupal that users be able to put comment on each paragraph  of an article beside putting comment on the whole article.

I use explode command to make an array which contains paragraphs:

```
$paragraphs = explode("<p>",render($content));
```

In order to put comment for the whole article I write:

```
print render($content['comments']);
```

I am trying to find the file where $content is defined, so I can add another array like `$content[]['paragraphcomments']`  for comments for each paragraph of an article. Does anyone know in which file $content is defined. Also does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: You need to post this on the Drupal version of this site:  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of print rendering the whole content in one step, you need to print render each field separately.
See this [drupal answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30063/how-to-print-fields-in-node-tpl-php) for details.

Then if you have a particular field that needs to have a different way of rendering you might try creating a template for the field. see [theme hooks](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) on the naming conventions for creating this template.